# How can I use this pointer with pointer to member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, this-pointer

I have typedef for a function pointer:

```
typedef bool(WlanApiWrapper::* (connect_func) )(WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK, const char *, const char *);
```

and have a method that returns a pointer to function:

```
const auto connect_method = map_algorithm_to_method(*network)
```

So I want to call that like that:

```
(*this.*connect_method)(*network, ssid, pass);
```

but gets error:

```
Error (active)  E0315   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function CppWlanHack C:\Projects\CppWlanHack\CppWlanHack\WlanApiWrapper.cpp  52
```

but when I call that like that:

```
WlanApiWrapper f;
(f.*connect_method)(*network, ssid, pass);
```

all is building...

How can I call the method without creating an object, because I've already had an object (this pointer)

Comment: Do you, by any chance, happen to try to do what you're trying to do in a const method? Note that your `connect_func` type is a pointer to a non-const member function…

Comment: When people ask you to post a reproducible example, do so instead of deleting your question. You *can* parse space separated numbers with `long.Parse("3 567",NumberStyles.Number, new NumberFormatInfo{NumberGroupSeparator=" "})`. The separator may not be an actual space though, it may be a non-breaking space or something similar

Answer (score 1):

The error message sounds to me like you're calling a non-const member function pointer inside a const member function. `this` is a `const WlanApiWrapper *` inside a const member function so `the object (*this) has type qualifiers (const) that are not compatible with the (non-const) member function`.

To solve this, you can either make the `connect_method` const or make the member function that contains `(this->*connect_method)(*network, ssid, pass);` non-const.

Comment: For completeness' sake, one might add that either the member function containing the call through the member function pointer has to be made non-const, *or* the member function pointer has to point to a const member function. In light of what the name `connect_func` suggests, the latter is most likely not going to work in the case at hand though…

Answer (score 0):

Call it like this:

```
((*this).*connect_method)(*network, ssid, pass);
```

This should work with all compilers.

For more info, read [How can I avoid syntax errors when calling a member function using a pointer-to-member-function?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn) in C++ FAQ

Comment: The unary `*` operator has higher precedence than the `.*` operator, so that shouldn't be the issue here. I do agree though that the use of additional parentheses would make the whole thing slightly more pleasant on the eyes…

Comment: Why not use `this->*connect_method` instead?